# Angular HttpClient get method subscribe Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, observable, subscription, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to determine whether file exists, by using httpclient's method get.

Then based on the outcome if file exists or not call one method with different argument.

```
 public faviconLogic(iconName: string): void {
    this.getFile(`assets/favicon/${iconName}/favicon.ico`)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.setFavicon(iconName),
      () => this.setFavicon('default')
    );
  }

  private getFile(filename: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.http.get(filename, { responseType: 'blob' });
  }
```

When entering method faviconlogic I get error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at t.applyUpdate
```

I tried adding headers - nothing. Calling method getFile itself works without problem lays with subscription to Observable returned on get. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `applyUpdate` your code but not included in your question? Are you calling `length` somewhere?

Comment: Nope, I'm not calling applyUpdate anywhere nor length. applyUpdate is supposedly a method from HttpHeaders.

Comment: In that case we would need a stackblitz reproducing your error...

Comment: @Morlas can you share code for `adding headers`? The error tells that you're setting `undefined` for headers

Comment: @Vadi `public getFile(filename: string, contentType: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(filename, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon' }) });
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was with authorization token in Http Headers.

Comment: can you explain a bit what happened please? I'm stuck at the same problem

Comment: Do you have any interceptors set up? There is probably a list of file types accepted by http get and you are missing the file type declaration